# What is this written in?

Tags: embedded, hardware, motion

I am dealing with an circa 80's era machine controller. A program is being downloaded to the operator's control panel and for the life of me I can't figure out what it is written.

The machine is a Cybermation 700A plasma cutting machine and here is a snippet of what being download.

Note that this is use to manage the download of cnc files into the machine it is not the motion control program itself. That I actually know how to write. It is this program that is proving to be the stumbling block.

```
    $70=A
    $72=0
    $73=6900
    $74=150
    $52=0
    $53=-8.516
    $84=200
    $85=0
    $10=0
    $98=0
    $71=0
    $18=0
    $76=.01
    $93=100
    $94=200
    $20=22-26 gauge;$21=.032;$22=260;$23=80;$24=0
    $25=18-20 gauge;$26=.033;$27=180;$28=80;$29=0
    $30=14-16 gauge;$31=.035;$32=150;$33=75;$34=0
    $35=10-12 gauge;$36=.043;$37=90;$38=60;$39=0
    $40=3/16-1/4 plate;$41=.053;$42=30;$43=30;$44=0

    $22=300
    $24=50
    $27=200
    $29=50
    $32=140
    $34=50
    $37=100
    $39=50
    $42=32
    $44=50
    $72=0
    $73=6900
    $74=150
    TV127,1
    $88=-s 30,300
    TV20,60
    TV22,5
    TV23,200
    TV25,6
    TV40,75
    TV42,5
    TV43,400
    TV45,6
    $9=80
    TV8,2500;W20,K99
    TV86,1

    {2
    TV7,$9     
   <1Select Plate
    $6=$5
    Tv112,16
    A
    >1!Torch on $16 min
    <2Enter plate number;V8,6
    >1Plate\:$6
    <2>Are you cutting $20?
    Y;$7=$21;$8=$22;$9=$23
    $71=$24;G3:
    <2>Are you cutting $25?
    Y;$7=$26;$8=$27;$9=$28
    $71=$29;G3:
    <2>Are you cutting $30?
    Y;$7=$31;$8=$32;$9=$33
    $71=$34;G3:
    <2>Are you cutting $35?
    Y;$7=$36;$8=$37;$9=$38
    $71=$39;G3:
    <2>Are you cutting $40?
    Y;$7=$41;$8=$42;$9=$43
    $71=$44;G3:
    G2
    }
    {3
    TV13,$71
    A
    G70
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It's probably some internal language or control parameters. It's specific to your machine.

Comment: I hope to heck that isn't the actual program. It looks like the output from a compiler to me. I feel your pain

Comment: What are you wanting to do?  Best way to learn a protocol is to reverse it :)

Comment: It text editable, if I change some of the strings that are used for prompts it show up when I download it again. Once even swapped the order of two major section of code and it still worked with the actions reversed. There is a EPROM with firmware that it is undoubtable using for the motion control. My hope is that the author used some obscure 80s scripting langauge as a template for his parser. So hence my question.

Comment: Also this downloads into a basic control that has a LCD and a keypad. So again I am hoping the author is using another product's codes as a template for his own.

Comment: If you don't get an answer on here email me offline.  I'd like to help you figure out this controller. (I have been looking for a good challenge)

Comment: Have you considered asking them?
http://www.cimtec-inc.com/

Comment: My company would be considered a competitor. And yes I pointed out to my boss that we would be saving a lot of time and $$$ if we could come to an arrangement.

Comment: I know that this answer is probably 5 years too late, but...  I was the author of the original Cymbermation software.  What you are looking at is very simple extension of the tool control language I developed.  $ introduces a variable, = an assignment, etc. This allowed parameterized programs able to cut entire families of shapes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cybermation plasma cutter uses Hypertherm HT40C cutting system and [Venix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venix) running "CFC 800/900 Office System" according to [this post](http://www.homekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/hvac/2701/Cybermation-Plasma-Cutter-need-software). According to Wikipedia Venix ran on DEC PRO-350, DEC Rainbow 100, and on IBM PC.

You could probably contact DEC community who may be familiar with Venix like people in [Xhomer project](http://xhomer.isani.org/xhomer/xhomer.html) (DEC emulator), or find someone who worked on Cybermation. For example, by Google search I found [Bob Donovan](http://www.1bdd.com/homepage/qualifications.html) who runs consulting service now, but used to work for Cybermation. Inc. - Woburn, MA.

> Built and debugged proto-type
>   electro-mechanical designs employing
>   both digital and analog circuitry for
>   a micro-computer controlled three axis
>   flame cutting machine.  Interfaced
>   plasma gas torches, routing tools, and
>   servo drive systems for
>   micro-processor control.  Guided new
>   product transitions from Engineering
>   to Manufacturing by designing test
>   fixtures, writing test procedures,
>   drafting schematics, creating BOMS,
>   and releasing ECOs.  Trained test
>   technicians and assemblers. 
>   Programmed the user interface for an
>   NC controller.  Wrote diagnostic
>   software using 6801 assembler. Managed
>   and repaired the Administration and
>   Engineering computer network system
>   (VAX 11/750, MicroVAX I & 3100, PCs,
>   terminals, and printers).  Managed and
>   programmed the engineering data base. 
>   Knowledgeable of the following
>   operating systems and applications:
>   Unix (as well as Ultrix, Venix,  &
>   XENIX), DOS, and Windows. Programming
>   experience in C, Basic, CSH/Bourne
>   shell script, and DOS batch files.

I also found the PO box and phone number for Cybermation in Woburn by Googling:

PO BOX 2007.

(781)-938-5555

Comment: We know about the company and the hardware however the Bob Donovan information is excellent! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are perhaps a set of output format control statements rather than an actual program.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess as i do not know your particular machine or any of that age.

Most CNC machines use [gcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) for programming, what you have there *may* be "semi compiled" gcode or perhaps a custom but related language.

Comment: No it is definitely code that controls the menus of the operator's panel and it initiates the download of gcode. I have captured the gcode download separately and that I do understand (it is in ESSI format). It is this portion that has me baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in Assembly Language.

It's designed to take inputs from the panel and output parameters to the Machine Control Unit.

It's basically asking what thickness sheet steel the plasma table is cutting, to control the cutting speed.

Comment: Yes I got that from reading the code. But I need to understand the langauge in order to write our own to be compatible with this type of machine.